# Spyder and Quandl issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder, quandl

I just instaled Quandl on my setup.
I'm running Spyder, Anaconda3, Windows 7.
The install was fine and Quandl is running as expected.
The only issue is I'm unable to see the entire output from my request. This is an extract of when more than 60 rows are availabe. It is able to print up to 60 rows whit this at the middle of the output::

```
2006-04-30  279.875665
2006-05-31  275.377411
2006-06-30  265.594889
2006-07-31  246.684074
2006-08-31  255.533319
2006-09-30  277.313945
2006-10-31  242.113468
               ...
2012-04-30  313.606557
2012-05-31  317.933637
2012-06-30  306.608700
2012-07-31  314.140902
2012-08-31  327.582875
2012-09-30  371.319479
2012-10-31  335.759077
```

At the bottom of the output I have the fowolling:

```
[125 rows x 1 columns]
```

This indicates my script knows how many rows are out there but is somehow unable to print all of them.
I'm observing this scenario on every request containing more than 60 rows.
Some examples:

```
import quandl
mydata = quandl.get("AUSBS/6291014A_A91718J")

import quandl
mydata = quandl.get("FRED/GDP")
```

and many more.
I tryed to fix it by "start" and "end", also fixed number of rows but with no success:

```
start_date="2001-12-31", end_date="2005-12-31"
rows=100
```

I belive my API key is correct. It looks like I'm able to get back just small part of my request. Something like a semple data. This is from Quandl website:

> If a valid API key is not used, some datatables will default to
>   returning sample data. If you are not receiving all expected data,
>   please double check your API key.

I checked my KEY many times and I'm sure it's correct.
Any suggestions of how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking for why is that happening but the decision is the `print` statement to be modified. From:

```
import quandl
data = quandl.get('FRED/GDP')
print(data)
```

To:

```
import quandl
data = quandl.get('FRED/GDP')
print(data.to_csv())
```